# Delphi's subrange types in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, delphi, clr, pascal

In Delphi (or any Pascal) you can declare sub-range type so if you try assign value from outside allowed range, you would get compiler error.

```
var
    i: 1..8;
begin
    i := 8; // i := 9 would not work
```

Can this be done in C#? I can imagine creating custom struct, something like `SubrangeType<byte>` but I'm looking for something builtin.

*EDIT:* xanatos's and DavidHeffernan's comments gave me idea for more specific question. Subrange checking in Delphi is available both in run-time and compile-time.  Implementing that on run-time would be possible in C# using custom struct but would it be possible to implement that checking on compile-time in C#?

Comment: Are the subranges separate types (so your i can "receive" the value from an int) or are simply compile-time checks?

Comment: @xanatos- yes you can "receive" int value. this is compile-time support (not only check but also you can have for example a for loop which automatically will iterate only from 1 to 8) silly example but to give you idea.

Comment: @xanatos There is both compile time and runtime checking. The runtime checking is optional and is, obviously, for scenarios such as you describe where the compiler cannot verify correctness.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - yes, with $R directive on this can be checked in runtime as well.

Comment: I don't see how your edit changes anything. Without language support for integral types of user-specified range, you cannot hope for help at compile time.

Comment: @jeroen This question asks "is there an equivalent in C#", but that question asks "why is there no equivalent in Java, C# and C++"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C# has no built-in language feature that is equivalent to Pascal subranges.